# Proving $\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j {n \choose j} F_{s+2n-2j} = F_{s+n} $, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number

Tags: combinatorics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

> $$\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j {n \choose j} F_{s+2n-2j} = F_{s+n} $$
>
> ($F$ is Fibonacci number).

I have been trying to  prove this by mathematical induction.
First I assume this is true for n.
If I could prove it works for n+1, then it is done.
$\sum_{j=0}^{n+1} (-1)^j {n+1 \choose j} F_{s+2n-2j+2} = F_{s+n+1} $
Also I could replace s with s+1 since it is valid for general constant s.
So I could get $\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j {n \choose j} F_{s+1+2n-2j} = F_{s+1+n} $

Comment: Good request Xia. Could you please add the basis step and what you think is the induction step? It will help those who read your request by saving time and understanding better how you are seeing the problem (And those like me who will come later on when they face the same proof problem).

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\,(-1)^j\,\binom{n}{j}\,z^{s+2(n-j)}=z^s\,\sum_{j=0}^n\,\binom{n}{j}\,(-1)^j\,\left(z^2\right)^{(n-j)}\,.$$
Using the Binomial Theorem,
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\,(-1)^j\,\binom{n}{j}\,z^{s+2(n-j)}=z^s\,\big((-1)+z^2\big)^n=z^s\,\left(z^2-1\right)^n\,.$$
If $z$ satisfies $z^2-z-1=0$, then $z\in\{\omega,\bar{\omega}\}$, where $\omega:=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\bar{\omega}:=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  Observe that $z^2-1=z$ for $z\in\{\omega,\bar{\omega}\}$, whence
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\,(-1)^j\,\binom{n}{j}\,z^{s+2(n-j)}=z^s\,\left(z^2-1\right)^n=z^s\,z^n=z^{s+n}\text{ for }z\in\{\omega,\bar{\omega}\}\,.$$

> Note that the $k$-th Fibonacci number $F_k$ is given by $$F_k=\frac{\omega^k-\bar{\omega}^k}{\omega-\bar\omega}\text{ for }k=0,1,2,\ldots\,.$$ This proves that $$\begin{align}\sum_{j=0}^n\,(-1)^j\,\binom{n}{j}\,F_{s+2(n-j)}&=\sum_{j=0}^n\,(-1)^j\,\binom{n}{j}\,\left(\frac{\omega^{s+2(n-j)}-\bar{\omega}^{s+2(n-j)}}{\omega-\bar{\omega}}\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{\omega-\bar\omega}\,\small\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\,(-1)^j\,\binom{n}{j}\,\omega^{s+2(n-j)}-\sum_{j=0}^n\,(-1)^j\,\binom{n}{j}\,\bar{\omega}^{s+2(n-j)}\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{\omega-\bar\omega}\,\left(\omega^{s+n}-\bar{\omega}^{s+n}\right)=F_{s+n}\,. \end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, define the *left-shift operator* $S$ on any real- or complex-valued sequence $\left(a_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}$ by
$$(Sa)_k:=a_{k+1}\text{ for all }k=0,1,2,\ldots\,.$$
For an operator $T$, we define $T^0$ to be the identity operator $I$ (namely, $(Ia)_k:=a_k$ for all $k=0,1,2,\ldots$), and $$\left(T^ra\right)_k:=\big(T\left(T^{r-1}a\right)\big)_k$$ for $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ and $k=0,1,2,\ldots$.
Now, the *$2$-step forward difference* $\Delta_2$ is defined to be $\Delta_2:=S^2-I$; that is,
$$(\Delta_2 a)_k=(S^2a)_k-(Ia)_k=a_{k+2}-a_k\text{ for each }k=0,1,2,\ldots\,.$$
In particular, 
$$(\Delta_2 F)_k=F_{k+2}-F_k=F_{k+1}=(SF)_k\text{ for each }k=0,1,2,\ldots\,.$$
In other words, $\Delta_2$ acts the same way as $S$ on the Fibonacci sequence.

The hint is to show that $$\Delta_2^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\,(-1)^j\,\binom{n}{j}\,S^{2(n-j)}\,,$$ which gives
$$(\Delta_2^n F)_s=\sum_{j=0}^n\,(-1)^j\,\binom{n}{j}\,F_{s+2(n-j)}$$ for any $s,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  Since $\Delta_2$ acts like $S$ on the Fibonacci sequence, and $\Delta_2$ and $S$ are commuting operators, we can then conclude that
$$(\Delta_2^n F)_s=(S^nF)_s=F_{n+s}\,.$$

Comment: "In other words, $\Delta_2$ acts the same way as $S$ on the Fibonacci sequence"... and on its images under $S^k$ for all $k$. This is important -- just knowing that two operators $A$ and $B$ act the same way on a given sequence  $v$ (in the sense of $Av = Bv$) does not automatically imply that $A^k v = B^k v$ for all $k\geq 0$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg That is simply due to the fact that $S$ commutes with $\Delta_2$, but I thought this observation was obvious due to the fact that $\Delta_2$ is a polynomial in $S$.  But you are right: if $A$ and $B$ do not commute, you cannot say that $A^kv=B^kv$.  Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof by induction over $n$.  To recap, we want to show
$$F_{s+n} = \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} F_{s+2n-2j} \tag{1}$$
The base case, $n=0$, is trivial.  So suppose (1) holds for some value of $n$.  We want show it holds for $n+1$.  Since $s$ is arbitrary, we may substitute $s+1$ for $s$ in (1):
$$F_{s+n+1} = \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} F_{s+1+2n-2j}$$
Next, we apply the Fibonacci identity $F_{n} = F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}$:
$$F_{s+n+1} = \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} (F_{s+2+2n-2j}-F_{s+2n-2j})$$
So
$$\begin{align}
F_{s+n+1} &= \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} F_{s+2+2n-2j} - \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} F_{s+2n-2j} \\
&= F_{s+2+2n} +  \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} F_{s+2+2n-2j} - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} F_{s+2n-2j} - (-1)^n F_s \\
&= F_{s+2+2n} +  \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} F_{s+2+2n-2j} - \sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j-1} \binom{n}{j-1} F_{s+2+2n-2j} - (-1)^n F_s \tag{2}\\
&= F_{s+2+2n} +  \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^j \left[ \binom{n}{j} + \binom{n}{j-1} \right] F_{s+2+2n-2j} +(-1)^{n+1}F_s \\
&= F_{s+2+2n} +  \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^j  \binom{n+1}{j}  F_{s+2+2n-2j} +(-1)^{n+1}F_s \tag{3}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n+1} (-1)^j \binom{n+1}{j} F_{s+2(n+1)-2j}
\end{align}$$

This completes the proof by induction.

**Notes**

(2) Shifting the index in the second sum

(3) Applying the recursive formula for binomial coefficients